Figure out system state to turn power off
I have a mobile robot base that has a computer running Ubuntu onboard and a seperate microcontroller for power management. What would be the best way to make sure that the computer has shut down completely before turning the system power off? I have control over both devices and can make reasonable modifications to them for this.
I have tried a systemd service which, when it gets stopped by systemd on poweroff, sends a UDP packet to the microcontroller to tell it to turn off power after a delay, but sometimes the system doesn't shut down in time. Would it be possible to keep this service and the network stack up until just before the system powers off?

Ended up hijacking the unused M.2 header to read from a 3.3v pin that goes low when the system is powered down.
